# PySpark: Filter data based on a date range from another data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to select records from **df1** if `df1.date1` lies between `df2.date2` and `df2.date3` (only three ranges of date2, date3 combination, row-wise, are allowed).

In my case there is no common variable to establish a 'join' criteria. I tried different pyspark.sql functions such as 'filter','when', 'withColumn', 'date_sub', 'date_add' etc. but unable to find a solution.

I did go through several SO posts, however, most of them propose to use 'join' which might not fit my problem!

***df1***

```
+----------+-----------+
|  emp_id  |   date1   |
+----------+-----------+
|   67891  | 11-13-2015|
|   12345  | 02-28-2017|
|   34567  | 04-07-2017|
+----------+-----------+
```

***df2***

```
+------------+------------+
|  date2     |   date3    |
+------------+------------+
|01-28-2017  | 03-15-2017 |
|07-13-2017  | 11-13-2017 |
|06-07-2018  | 09-07-2018 |
+------------+------------+
```

***Expected record***:

```
+----------+-----------+
|  emp_id  |   date1   |
+----------+-----------+
|   12345  | 02-28-2017|
+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: You could combine the 2 dataframes by joining on a dummy id column and there filter the dates out. Also, do you wanna compare date1 with each of the date2 and date3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do non-equi joins in spark. You don't necessarily need matching keys.

This is in scala, am pretty sure it's almost the same in python. Lemme know if it doesn't work. Will update the answer in pyspark as well.

```
scala> df1.join(df2 , 'date1 > 'date2 && 'date1 < 'date3).show
    +------+----------+----------+----------+
    |emp_id|     date1|     date2|     date3|
    +------+----------+----------+----------+
    | 12345|02-28-2017|01-28-2017|03-15-2017|
    +------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Pyspark solution:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime
>>> x = [(67891 ,'11-13-2015'),(12345, '02-28-2017'),(34567,'04-07-2017')]
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame(x,['emp_id','date1'])
>>> y = [('01-28-2017','03-15-2017'),('07-13-2017','11-13-2017'),('06-07-2018','09-07-2018')]
>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame(y,['date2','date3'])
>>> df1a = df1.select('emp_id', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('date1', 'MM-dd-yyy')).alias('date1'))
>>> df2a = df2.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('date2', 'MM-dd-yyy')).alias('date2'),from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('date3', 'MM-dd-yyy')).alias('date3'))


>>> df1a.join(df2a, on=[df1a['date1'] > df2a['date2'], df1a['date1'] < df2a['date3']]).show()
+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|emp_id|              date1|              date2|              date3|
+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 12345|2017-02-28 00:00:00|2017-01-28 00:00:00|2017-03-15 00:00:00|
+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Excellent! your solution worked like a charm. Initially, I tried non-equi joins as well because I was expecting join conditions to work better when features are in 'date' type. But, did not know the power of 'unix_timestamp','from_unixtime' functions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help